Spring Boot 3 + Multiple DataSources: Integration Tests fail to start
to start with, this is about Spring Boot 3.1.9, Java Temurin 17.
Using https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources, I've successfully setup two datasources (actually, it's the same DB, but for one Entity, I need a separate Hikari connection pool).
The setup below leads to error message Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument - although it should have used the definitions from the @Configuration classes DefaultJpaConfiguration/LockingJpaConfiguration.
When I disable @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan (as I had to do for the productive code), the error message does not change.
I know, that @DataJpa tests ignore any handmade DataSource definitions, but I did not find any such statement in @SpringBootTest. So maybe I'm missing something here - can you help me out?
I've tried to apply

Spring Boot test configuration for multiple datasources
Tests not working for multiple datasource with spring boot liquibase
but that did not improve anything.

My classes look as described in the article:
An Entity, using the default connection pool:
package com.application.database.model.stock;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "vehicleSeq", sequenceName = "VEHICLE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "vehicleSeq")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;
    
}

The default Entity's Repository:
package com.application.database.repository;

import com.application.database.model.stock.Vehicle;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {
    Optional<Vehicle> findVehicleByColor(String color);
}

The default connection pool's configuration:
package com.application.database.config;

import com.application.database.model.dealer.Dealer;
import com.application.database.model.file.WfsFileImport;
import com.application.database.model.location.Location;
import com.application.database.model.reactivation.ManualReactivation;
import com.application.database.model.stock.Vehicle;
import com.application.database.model.thirdpartyexport.DealerContactDataForThirdPartyExportQueryResult;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.application.database.repository", "com.application.database.model" },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultJpaConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defaultEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("defaultDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages(Vehicle.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("defaultEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defaultEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(defaultEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource defaultDataSource() {
        return defaultDataSourceProperties()
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.default")
    public DataSourceProperties defaultDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
}

And now the Entity, using other connection pool ("locking"):
package com.application.database.locking.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;
import java.util.UUID;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator.Style;

@Table(name = "lock")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Lock {

    @Id
    @UuidGenerator(style = Style.RANDOM)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "UUID")
    private UUID id;
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id")
    private Long vehicleId;
}

The other Entity's Repository:
package com.application.database.locking.repository;

import com.application.database.locking.model.Lock;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public interface LockRepository extends JpaRepository<Lock, Long> {
    Optional<Lock> findByVehicleId(Long vehicleId);
}

The other connection pool's configuration:
package com.application.database.config;

import com.application.database.locking.model.Lock;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.application.database.locking.repository", "com.application.database.locking.model" },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "lockingEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "lockingTransactionManager"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LockingJpaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lockingEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("lockingDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages(Lock.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager lockingTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("lockingEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lockingEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(lockingEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource lockingDataSource() {
        return lockingDataSourceProperties()
            .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.locking")
    public DataSourceProperties lockingDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
}

The config properties:
spring:
  datasource:
    default:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/postgres
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    locking:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/postgres
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

I had to adjust the Application class (used to start the application), one I removed @EnableJpaRepositories and @EntityScan, I was able to start the application:
package com.application.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application")
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application")
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.application") <- had to be disabled/removed, to get application starting
//@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.application") <- had to be disabled/removed, to get application starting
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Now, we have both, Integration and @DataJpa tests. The @DataJpa tests look like the following:
package com.application.database.repository;

import static java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
class LockRepositoryTest {

    /* Test code omitted */

    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.application")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.application")
    @SpringBootApplication
    static class TestConfiguration {}
}

This test boots the application and successfully concluded.
But the story is different, when running an IntegrationTest, such as this one:
package com.application.database.repository;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@ContextConfiguration( <- leads to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available
//    classes = { DefaultJpaConfiguration.class, LockingJpaConfiguration.class },
//    loader= AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class
//)
class QueryRepositoryTest {

    /* Test code omitted */

    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.application") <- disabling it changes nothing
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.application") <- disabling it changes nothing
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application")
    @SpringBootApplication
    static class TestConfiguration {}
}

Please do not hesitate to contact me, if you need any further information/code and something to be tried.
Thanks.
kniffte

I was able to resolve the issue.
We had a couple more integration tests in the same module (we do not share test code between the modules) that all had the following (comparable) setup:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
class IntegrationTestClass {

    // some tests here...

    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application")
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.application")
    @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.application")
    @SpringBootApplication
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
    static class TestConfiguration {}

}

This setup was picked up during the integration test (since it searched for all @Configuration classes.
I've got it resolved by changing the test class to
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@Import({ IntegrationTestClass.TestConfiguration.class })
class IntegrationTestClass {

    // some tests here...

    @TestComponentScan
    @SpringBootApplication
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
    static class TestConfiguration {}

}

and by adding the TestComponentScan annotation:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application",
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = {
        ".*TestConfiguration"
    }))
public @interface TestComponentScan {}

Important: there can be no class still using the original way of defining the context.
Also, when manually defining the ConnectionPools, SpringBoot does not seem to employ the spring.jpa.generate-ddl setting to the new ConnectionPools. I therefore had to set this setting using Hibernate 6's configuration options.
The JpaConfiguration (same for both) (just the changed parts):
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JpaConfigurationProperties.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.application.database.repository", "com.exxeta.dfstp.geofence.core.database.model" },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "defaultEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "defaultTransactionManager"
)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultJpaConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean defaultEntityManagerFactory(
        @Qualifier("defaultDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        JpaConfigurationProperties jpaConfig,
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {

        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("com.application.database.repository", "com.application.database.model")
            .properties(jpaConfig.getProperties())
            .build();
    }

with new class JpaConfigurationProperties:
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.jpa", ignoreInvalidFields = true)
public class JpaConfigurationProperties {
    private final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}

and the configuration settings in the application-test.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action: drop-and-create # set to none for productive code
    generate-ddl: true
    # ignored due to two connection pools, replaced by spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action
    # hibernate:
    #   ddl-auto: create-drop

Maybe this might help somebody else...
Thanks for your support.
kniffte
